# Firebase: Best practice to build a data structure that can filter data by multiple criteria quickly

Tags: firebase, data-structures, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

For example, I have a list of 1.000.000 users, the data look like this:

```
users: {
  $userId: {
    name: "",
    sex: "",
    age: "",
    city: "",
    maritalStatus: "",
    // can be more
  }
}
```

I want to **filter**, **paginate** the data for: users who are single, male, with age < 30, living in city X.

Is there a good practice to make this kind of queries less painful?

Comment: There is a library that makes this simpler: https://github.com/davideast/Querybase

Answer (score 2):

Firebase doesn't have a a direct way to query for more than one child at a time.

You can structure your data to make it easier - for example

```
users
  $userId
     gender_age:  male_27
  $userId
     gender_age:  male_32
```

Then, to query for males between 30 and 40:

```
gender_age....queryStartingAtValue("male_30").endingAtValue("male_40")
```

That will narrow down the results - you could then filter in code for the ones you want, for example (conceptual)

```
  if snapshot.child("maritalStatus") = "Single" and
     snapshot.child("city") = "AnyTown" then
         //add person to list for display
```

You could expand this out a bit to narrow the results further:

```
users
  $userId
     city_gender_age:  anytown_male_27

city_gender_age....queryStartingAtValue("anytown_male_30").endingAtValue("anytown_male_40")
```

Unfortunately the pattern breaks down if the query is less specific; e.g. if we are querying for either male or female in anytown between 30 and 40, this won't work.

However, disk space is cheap so storing 'duplicate' data in another node would resolve that

```
another_node
   $user_id
      city_age: anytown_27
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still open to any answers.

Comment: @ThịnhPhạm this is as good as it gets.. nosql databases are like this. I don't know why they are SO popular when they are only useful in corner cases in my opinion.